# Default value of 'boolean' and 'Boolean' in Java

Tags: java, boolean, default-value

What are the default values of `boolean` (primitive) and `Boolean` (primitive wrapper) in Java?

Answer (score 626, accepted):

The default value for a `Boolean` (object) is `null`.
The [default value](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) for a `boolean` (primitive) is `false`.

Answer (score 418):

The default value of any `Object`, such as `Boolean`, is `null`.

The default value for a `boolean` is false.

**Note:** Every primitive has a wrapper class. Every wrapper uses a reference which has a default of `null`. Primitives have different default values:

```
boolean -> false

byte, char, short, int, long -> 0

float, double -> 0.0
```

**Note (2):** `void` has a wrapper `Void` which also has a default of `null` and is it's only possible value (without using hacks).

Comment: I think one could mention `Boolean` is `Object`, that would make the first line meaning obvious. This sounds pretty basic, but for someone asking a basic question like this it may help.

Answer (score 28):

**boolean**
Can be `true` or `false`.
Default value is `false`.

(Source: [Java Primitive Variables](http://www.fluffycat.com/Java/Primitive-Variables/))

**Boolean**
Can be a `Boolean` object representing `true` or `false`, *or* can be `null`.
Default value is `null`.

Answer (score 16):

If you need to ask, then you need to explicitly initialize your fields/variables, because if you have to look it up, then chances are someone else needs to do that too.

The value for a primitive `boolean` is false as can be seen [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).

As mentioned by others the value for a `Boolean` will be null by default.

Comment: Thank you for reference to official source. As to initialization, there is no need to compensate for a lack of knowledge.

Comment: 'Lack of knowledge' implies that there is some expected level to compare to. If this minimal knowledge level is clear, I agree. If not, I find it prudent to err on being more explicit. In all this is a rather personal/team decision/opinion.

Comment: @LoBo - I think there is nothing wrong with compensating for a potential lack of knowledge. You don't know who will be maintaining your code down the line. Anything that makes your code more easily understood and/or readable, while having little impact on performance, can only be a good thing.

Comment: I agree with @Lobo on this one. You should assume your future code reader knows how to write Java code. It is a bad idea to explain how Java works, in the code. That's what stackoverflow is for.

Answer (score 9):

Boolean is an Object.  So if it's an instance variable it will be null.  If it's declared within a method you will have to initialize it, or there will be a compiler error.

If you declare as a primitive i.e. boolean.  The value will be false by default if it's an instance variable (or class variable).  If it's declared within a method you will still have to initialize it to either true or false, or there will be a compiler error.

Answer (score 6):

An uninitialized `Boolean` member (actually a reference to an object of type `Boolean`) will have the default value of `null`.

An uninitialized `boolean` (primitive) member will have the default value of `false`.

Answer (score 4):

There is no default for `Boolean`. `Boolean` must be constructed with a `boolean` or a `String`. If the object is unintialized, it would point to `null`.

The default value of primitive `boolean` is `false`.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: I think those 3 downvotes are because you say "there is no default" which is a fairly unclear statement. As you say, an uninitialized object reference points to `null`. `null` is the default, so I'm not sure what you are referring to when you say there isn't one. (Did you maybe mean something like "`Boolean` is neither `true` nor `false` by default"?)

Comment: Yes, what you put is more accurate. There is already an accepted answer that is more concise. I'm not sure what is gained by both downvoting a post and editing it.

Comment: To clarify, I didn't downvote and my edit was completely unrelated to my comment. I'd recommend editing the answer if you approve of that suggested phrasing, and then we can delete our comments to clean up.

Comment: This answer contains misleading/partially false information and it should be downvoted/removed in its current state.

Comment: @improbable what is misleading / partially false? Can you clarify?

Comment: > There is no default for `Boolean`

@StealthRabbi

Answer (score 2):

```
class BooleanTester
{
    boolean primitive;
    Boolean object;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BooleanTester booleanTester = new BooleanTester();
        System.out.println("primitive: " + booleanTester.getPrimitive());
        System.out.println("object: " + booleanTester.getObject());
}

    public boolean getPrimitive() {
        return primitive;
    }

    public Boolean getObject() {
        return object;
    }
}
```

output:

```
primitive: false
object: null
```

This seems obvious but I had a situation where Jackson, while serializing an object to JSON, was throwing an NPE after calling a getter, just like this one, that returns a primitive boolean which was not assigned. This led me to believe that Jackson was receiving a null and trying to call a method on it, hence the NPE. I was wrong.

Moral of the story is that when Java allocates memory for a primitive, that memory has a value even if not initialized, which Java equates to false for a boolean. By contrast, when allocating memory for an uninitialized complex object like a Boolean, it allocates only space for a reference to that object, not the object itself - there is no object in memory to refer to - so resolving that reference results in null.

I think that strictly speaking, "defaults to false" is a little off the mark. I think Java does not allocate the memory and assign it a value of false until it is explicitly set; I think Java allocates the memory and whatever value that memory happens to have is the same as the value of 'false'. But for practical purpose they are the same thing.