# data binding - safeUnbox warning

Tags: android, data-binding, android-gradle-plugin, warnings, android-databinding

after i upgrade AS gradle version to 2.3.0,
data binding encounter a warning :

> Warning:selectMap[index] is a boxed field but needs to be un-boxed to execute selectMap[index] ? @android:color/white : @android:color/transparent. This may cause NPE so Data Binding will safely unbox it. You can change the expression and explicitly wrap selectMap[index] with safeUnbox() to prevent the warning

selectMap is an ObservableMap, then i search this warning but got just few discussions and did not fix it

[Android Studio 2.3.0-alpha1: Databinding + int unboxing causes compile errors](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=228345)

[Databinding - data object is null on API 15-18](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=191841)

I follow the way in the links, modify `selectMap[index]` to `safeUnbox(selectMap[index])` but got syntax error.

So anyone know how to fix this warning?

---

Edit : 
Here is the xml file code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<data class="SupportCountryViewHolderBinding">

    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="com.goodarc.care_about.activity.account.support_country.SupportCountryHolderViewModel" />

    <variable
        name="dataSource"
        type="com.goodarc.care_about.module.assets_file.SupportCountry" />

    <variable
        name="selectMap"
        type="android.databinding.ObservableMap&lt;Integer, Boolean&gt;" />

    <variable
        name="index"
        type="int" />
</data>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@{selectMap[index] ? @android:color/white : @android:color/transparent}"
    android:onClick="@{(v) -> viewModel.onItemSelectListener(selectMap, index)}"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="20dp">

    <TextView
        style="@style/TitleLabel2"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|start"
        android:text="@{dataSource.display}"
        android:textColor="@{selectMap[index] ? @android:color/black : @android:color/white}"
        tools:text="Taiwan (+886)" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Build is succeed, but warning come out(i past above).

Comment: where is you code of question?

Answer (score 35):

I had the same warning, in my case changing the variable declaration from **Boolean** type to **boolean** type solve the problem:

From:

```
<variable
        name="readOnly"
        type="Boolean" />
```

To:

```
<variable
        name="readOnly"
        type="boolean" />
```

So, maybe you can try with:

```
<variable
    name="selectMap"
    type="android.databinding.ObservableMap&lt;Integer, boolean&gt;" />
```

Comment: Did you have the same problem with Strings? In my case was only with Boolean

Comment: Sorry there was no problem with String it was something else AFAIR

Answer (score 22):

You can add safeUnbox like this:

```
android:text="@{Double.toString(safeUnbox(product.listPrice))}"
```

Comment: I think safeUnbox is simple solution. ```public static boolean safeUnbox(java.lang.Boolean boxed) { return boxed == null ? false : (boolean) boxed; }``` in android.databinding.DynamicUtil

Comment: I'd not recommend using `safeUnbox` method. If a developer is using a nullable `Boolean` type and is setting it to `null`, probably he or she doesn not mean `false`. Use non nullable `boolean` type if you don't need nullability, handle `null` explicitly with custom adapter or - if you're using `Boolean` but don't expect `null` in the current state - just let the application throw `NPE` to warn you that there is a bug to be fixed.

Answer (score 17):

> w: warning: **enabled** is a boxed field but needs to be un-boxed
>   to execute **android:checked**.

This warning comes because **enabled field can be null**. If you take `Boolean` instead of `boolean`, so `Boolean` can be null. So this warning comes. That this field can make **`NullPointerException`**.

**---------------- Case 1 - One Way Binding----------------**

```
<variable
    name="enabled"
    type="Boolean"/>

....

<Switch
    android:checked="@{enabled}"
    />
```

#### Solution 1

```
<Switch
    android:checked="@{safeUnbox(fieldName)}"
    />
```

#### Solution 2

Change `Boolean` to primitive type `boolean`. So that it never be null, [default value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6226290/6891563) of `boolean` is `false`.

```
<variable
    name="enabled"
    type="boolean"/>
```

**---------------- Case 2 - Two-Way Binding----------------**
When you have two-way binding, then you can not use `safeUnbox()` way, because [`safeUnbox()` will not be inverted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47335090/6891563).

```
<variable
    name="enabled"
    type="Boolean"/>

....

<Switch
    android:checked="@={enabled}"
    />
```

<strike>**This will not work now.**</strike>

```
<Switch
    android:checked="@{safeUnbox(fieldName)}"
    />
```

#### Solution 1

Change `Boolean` to primitive type `boolean`. So that it never be null, [default value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6226290/6891563) of `boolean` is false.

```
<variable
    name="enabled"
    type="boolean"/>
```

#### Solution 2

A long way is to make **inverse binding adapters** for **safeUnbox**. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47337166/6891563).

#### What is safeUnbox() method?

`safeUnbox()` just check null value and return non-null value. You can see below methods which are defined in Data binding library.

```
public static int safeUnbox(java.lang.Integer boxed) {
    return boxed == null ? 0 : (int)boxed;
}
public static long safeUnbox(java.lang.Long boxed) {
    return boxed == null ? 0L : (long)boxed;
}
public static short safeUnbox(java.lang.Short boxed) {
    return boxed == null ? 0 : (short)boxed;
}
public static byte safeUnbox(java.lang.Byte boxed) {
    return boxed == null ? 0 : (byte)boxed;
}
public static char safeUnbox(java.lang.Character boxed) {
    return boxed == null ? '\u0000' : (char)boxed;
}
public static double safeUnbox(java.lang.Double boxed) {
    return boxed == null ? 0.0 : (double)boxed;
}
public static float safeUnbox(java.lang.Float boxed) {
    return boxed == null ? 0f : (float)boxed;
}
public static boolean safeUnbox(java.lang.Boolean boxed) {
    return boxed == null ? false : (boolean)boxed;
}
```

#### I explained about Boolean, this solution is same for `Integer`, `Double`, `Character` etc.

Answer (score 9):

Instead of `ObservableField<T>` you should use special version for the primitives:

1. `ObservableInt` for the `int`
2. `ObservableBoolean` for the `boolean`
3. `ObservableFloat` for the `float`
4. `ObservableChar` for the `char`
5. `ObservableLong` for the `long`
6. `ObservableByte` for the `byte`
7. `ObservableShort` for the `short`

Answer (score 6):

I had this warning popup when i did something like :

```
 android:visibility="@{viewmodel.isLoading ? View.INVISIBLE : View.VISIBLE}"
```

adding safeunbox like so :

```
 android:visibility="@{safeUnbox(viewmodel.isLoading) ? View.INVISIBLE : View.VISIBLE}"
```

removed the warning after rebuild

Answer (score 0):

This can appear as well whenever you are using a custom `BindingAdapter` so in my case I needed to make the second argument as nullable, and the warning went away.

```
@BindingAdapter("xyz")
fun xyzAdapter(view: View, value: Int?) {
  value?.let {
    //TODO
  }
}
```

I am not using Java, but if you are make sure to include `@Nullable` annotation, and do a null condition.

Answer (score -1):

Add the `safeUnbox()` to the warning variable will make this warning gone and it will still work well

```
android:alpha="@{alpha != null ? safeUnbox(alpha) : 0.5f}"
```