# safeUnbox() cannot be inverted

Tags: android, warnings, android-databinding

I'm trying to eliminate all the warnings of my Android application and one of them is this:

> viewModel.value is a boxed field but needs to be un-boxed to execute android:checked. This may cause NPE so Data Binding will safely unbox it. You can change the expression and explicitly wrap viewModel.value with safeUnbox() to prevent the warning

Where value is a generic `ObservableField` that comes from a super class:

```
public abstract class BaseDataTypeViewModel<T> extends BaseObservable  {
    public final ObservableField<T> value = new ObservableField<>();
    ...
}
```

And is extented somewhere as a `Boolean`:

```
public class CheckBooleanDataTypeViewModel extends BaseDataTypeViewModel<Boolean> {
    ...
}
```

I saw on [data binding - safeUnbox warning](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42872201/3520621) that the warnings happen because this is a `Boolean` and not a `boolean`, so I tried to add this: `android:checked="@={safeUnbox(viewModel.value)}"` instead of `android:checked="@={viewModel.value}"` but then I got an error saying I can't invert the `safeUnbox()` method.

> ****/ data binding error ****msg:The expression android.databinding.DynamicUtil.safeUnbox(viewModelValue) cannot be inverted: There is no inverse for method safeUnbox, you must add an @InverseMethod annotation to the method to indicate which method should be used when using it in two-way binding expressions

I understand correctly the 2 separated issues, but do I have to live with the warning to avoid the error or is their a solution to avoid both the warning and the error? What about the `@InverseMethod` it is talking about? I didn't manage to add this annotation because the method comes from the android package.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I haven't worked with Android Architecture Components or with the Data Binding libraries in this particular way, but I think I can still help.

Within your XML, you've got this:

```
android:checked="@={viewModel.value}"
```

The system is giving you a warning because it wants you to know that in the case where `viewModel.value` is `null`, it's going to do something special (behave as though it were `false` instead, presumably). It does this via the `safeUnbox()` method.

To solve the warning, it's suggesting making the `safeUnbox()` call explicit. You can't do that because there's no "inverse" of `safeUnbox()` to go *back* from `boolean` to `Boolean`.

But it doesn't sound like you have to use `safeUnbox()`; you could create your own method that converts `Boolean` to `boolean`, and then you could use the suggested annotation to declare which method will convert back from `boolean` to `Boolean`.

```
public class MyConversions {

    @InverseMethod("myBox")
    public static boolean myUnbox(Boolean b) {
        return (b != null) && b.booleanValue();
    }

    public static Boolean myBox(boolean b) {
        return b ? Boolean.TRUE : Boolean.FALSE;
    }
}
```

Now you can change your XML to:

```
android:checked="@={com.example.stackoverflow.MyConversions.myUnbox(viewModel.value)}"
```

I hope this helps. If it turns out that I'm way off-base, let me know; I'd love to learn more about this topic.

Most of what I have in this answer I learned from https://medium.com/google-developers/android-data-binding-inverse-functions-95aab4b11873

Comment: You did well understood the problem ! Nice way of resolving it. Just to be cleaner I imported the "com.example..." into an `<import>` tag.

Comment: Thanks for this! I created a class containing mappings for all Java primitive types. https://gist.github.com/pasmat/f1f8f04eeab4dde7dc9b534a51f67d15

Comment: I tried this but getting null pointer exception when doing livedata.getValue() in my ViewModel after changing my checkbox. I can see that it is running the boxing methods if I'm putting breakpoints and the warnings disappeared. Any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Came across this issue and found an easier solution. You can avoid this warning by creating a custom [BindingAdapter](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/binding-adapters) for the boxed type like this:

```
@BindingAdapter("android:checked")
public static void setChecked(CompoundButton checkableView, Boolean isChecked) {
    checkableView.setChecked(isChecked != null ? isChecked : false);
}
```

This solution can be replicated to any property like `visibility`, `enabled` etc. and to any boxed primitive like `Integer`, `Float` etc.

You can also provide the value to be used in case your `LiveData` value is `null` like this:

```
@BindingAdapter(value={"android:checked", "nullValue"}, requireAll=false)
public static void setChecked(CompoundButton checkableView, Boolean isChecked, boolean nullValue) {
    checkableView.setChecked(isChecked != null ? isChecked : nullValue);
}
```

And call it like this:

```
<CheckBox
    ...
    android:checked='@{viewModel.value}'
    app:nullValue="@{false}"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

do like this in xml. Last line of code is the most important.

```
<layout>

  <data>
    <import type="android.view.View"/>
    <variable name="entryViewModel"
        type="com.craiovadata.groupmap.viewmodel.EntryViewModel" />
  </data>

  <Button 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="@{safeUnbox(entryViewModel.showBtnMyGroups) ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE, default = gone}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I find a code ,this this **safeUnbox** implementation。

```
/** @hide */
protected static int safeUnbox(java.lang.Integer boxed) {
    return boxed == null ? 0 : (int)boxed;
}

/** @hide */
protected static long safeUnbox(java.lang.Long boxed) {
    return boxed == null ? 0L : (long)boxed;
}

/** @hide */
protected static short safeUnbox(java.lang.Short boxed) {
    return boxed == null ? 0 : (short)boxed;
}

/** @hide */
protected static byte safeUnbox(java.lang.Byte boxed) {
    return boxed == null ? 0 : (byte)boxed;
}

/** @hide */
protected static char safeUnbox(java.lang.Character boxed) {
    return boxed == null ? '\u0000' : (char)boxed;
}

/** @hide */
protected static double safeUnbox(java.lang.Double boxed) {
    return boxed == null ? 0.0 : (double)boxed;
}

/** @hide */
protected static float safeUnbox(java.lang.Float boxed) {
    return boxed == null ? 0f : (float)boxed;
}

/** @hide */
protected static boolean safeUnbox(java.lang.Boolean boxed) {
    return boxed == null ? false : (boolean)boxed;
}
```

so ,if you value is not base type,you can not direct use safeUnbox,**you should define a static function to safe unbox by youself.**