# What is the default value of a basic Boolean in Swift?

Tags: swift, boolean

I want to know about `Bool` in Swift.

If Bool is a basic primitive datatype, why is a Boolean's default value `nil`?

```
var test: Bool!
print(test) // nil
```

In Java the Boolean default value is false:

*[Default value of 'boolean' and 'Boolean' in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6226290/default-value-of-boolean-in-java)*

Comment: Please link to the thing you're referring to instead of posting a picture of it.

Comment: Note that `var test: Bool!` is no *yet* a Bool. The type is declared but the variable has no value. It is nil, therefore not true nor false.

Comment: @Moritz Now I understand Thanks

Comment: @GauravSaini, there's no such thing as `default value` for type in Swift, you must initialize each variable with specific value (except `Optional<T>` which has it, and it's `nil`).

Comment: @user28434 `Void` has an implicit default value too; try `let v: Void; print(v)`

Comment: @Hamish, ok `Void` is second exception, because it's a [`Unit`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_type) type, therefore there's only one value option for it.

Comment: Adding to what @user28434 has already stated, `Void` is just a type alias to the empty tuple, `()`, this is why it has only one possible value.

Comment: -side note
If you pull a Boolean from UserDefaults and it doesn’t have a set value, it will return false

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**`Bool`**, **`Bool!`** and **`Bool?`** all are different in **Swift**.

**1.** **`Bool`** is a **non-optional** data type that can have values - `true/false`. You need to initialize it in the initializer or while declaring it before using it.

```
var x : Bool = false

var x: Bool
init()
{
   x = false
}
```

**2.** **`Bool?`** is an **optional** data type that can have values - `nil/true/false`. In order to use this type, you need to unwrap it using `if let or force unwrapping`.

```
var x: Bool?

if let value = x
{
   //TODO: use value instead of x
}
```

**3.** **`Bool!`** is an **implicitly unwrapped optional** data type that can have values - `nil/true/false`. The difference here is it must contain a value before using it else it will result in `runtime exception`. Since it is implicitly unwrapped, no need to unwrap it using `if let or force unwrapping`.

```
var x: Bool! //Must contain value before using
```

Comment: "*an implicitly unwrapped optional [...] it must contain a value before using it else it will result in runtime exception*" – actually since Swift 3, the line is real blurry with that; if an IUO can be type checked as a strong optional, it will be. For example, `var x: Bool!; print("\(x)")` will not crash; it will just output `nil`.

Comment: thanks for the explanation!
I'm still new to swift and it's sometimes tidies

Answer (score 4):

Strictly spoken there is **no** default value in Swift.

- Either the `Bool` is **non-optional** then you have to assign a (default) value
- or if the `Bool` is an **optional**, then it is `nil` – which is *no value* in terms of Swift.

Comment: *Strictly spoken* there are default values for some intrinsic types in Swift. With `Optional`, while `nil` does indeed *express* "no value", it is a literal that represents the `.none` case of `Optional`, and is thus one of the possible values for it to have; and is not the same as being uninitialised. So `Optional` has an implicit default value of `.none`. It's not the only type with a default value; `Void` has a default value of `()`, `let v: Void; print(v)` is perfectly legal. (Although those are the only two types I can immediately think of with default values).

Answer (score 0):

`Bool` in Swift is **not** a primitive. Everything in Swift are objects. Your variable `test` is a `Bool!`, which is an implicitly unwrapped optional and the default value is `nil`.

If you use this code (not an optional),

```
var test: Bool
print(test)
```

You will get an error:

> variable 'test' used before being initialized

So in Swift you have to initialize stuff before you use it, for example:

```
var test: Bool = false
```

Comment: Saying that everything in "Swift" is an object is not good wording. `Bool` is a value type, which is what Java primitives are. You are right that every non-optional var needs to be initialized and optionals are `nil` by default.