# JSTL Boolean Null Pointer exception thrown

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jstl

I have a code where I am trying to display a cross or tick based on the value of a object property in JSTL. The property is of type Boolean and I am getting a java.lang.NullPointerException thrown in the jsp. My code is as follows

```
 <c:if test="${gem==true}">
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
 </c:if>

 <c:if test="${gem==false}">
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
 </c:if>
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this?

Comment: This means that `gem` is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using primitive boolean instead of Boolean else assign value to Boolean. By default Boolean Object value is null. Please refer: [Default value of Boolean in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6226290/default-value-of-boolean-in-java)