# My do while loop is stopping after one iteration. how do I keep it going?

Tags: java, loops

My code terminates after one iteration, even if `quit` is true.

```
import java.util.*;
public class calc {
public static  boolean quit;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    keepGoing();
}
public static void keepGoing() {
    do {

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = s.nextLine();
        String inputLower = input.toLowerCase();
        int findQuit = inputLower.indexOf("quit");
        if (findQuit != -1) {
            boolean quit = false;
        }

    } while (quit == true); {
    System.out.println("OTHER CODE GOES IN PLACE OF THIS PRINTLN");
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't specify value for static `quit`, it will be false (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6226290/default-value-of-boolean-and-boolean-in-java)). Then it is never updated in your code to true.

Answer (score 3):

The default value of a `boolean` is `false`. So change

```
public static  boolean quit;
```

to

```
public static  boolean quit = true;
```

**also** you currently only set it to `false` with a ***shadowed*** variable. Change

```
if (findQuit != -1) {
    boolean quit = false;
}
```

to

```
if (findQuit != -1) {
    quit = false;
}
```

**or** eliminate the `if` and assign the `boolean` directly like

```
quit = (findQuit == -1);
```

Finally, there is no need to check if a `boolean` `== true`. Change

```
while (quit == true);
```

to

```
while (quit);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize the variable *quit* first.
Do it while definition or after but it has to be before the do while loop begining.

```
public static boolean quit = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the quit variable as true. Because default value of boolean variable is false.

```
public static boolean quit = true;
```

You need to change this code:

```
if (findQuit != -1) {
      boolean quit = false;
}
```

To:

```
if (findQuit != -1) {
      quit = false;
}
```

Because no need to define quite variable again.

No need to heck boolean using equals. So change the code from:

```
while (quit == true);
    {
        System.out.println("OTHER CODE GOES IN PLACE OF THIS PRINTLN");
    }
```

To:

```
while (quit);
    {
        System.out.println("OTHER CODE GOES IN PLACE OF THIS PRINTLN");
    }
```

Full code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class calc {
public static boolean quit = true;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    keepGoing();
}

public static void keepGoing() {
    do {

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = s.nextLine();
        String inputLower = input.toLowerCase();
        int findQuit = inputLower.indexOf("quit");
        if (findQuit != -1) {
            quit = false;
        }

    } while (quit);
    {
        System.out.println("OTHER CODE GOES IN PLACE OF THIS PRINTLN");
    }
}
}
```